# Tensorflow Dataset won't output tensors to GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow-datasets

I have a list of Numpy arrays, `arr_list`. Because my arrays are all different shapes, I am trying to use the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` function to create a Tensorflow dataset using this list.

Here's my generator:

```py
def generator_func():
    for (a, b), c in arr_list:
        a = tf.cast(a, dtype=tf.uint16)
        b = tf.cast(b, dtype=tf.float16)
        c = tf.cast(c, dtype=tf.float32)
        yield (a, b), c
```

For context, `a` and `b` are the inputs to my model, and `c` is the output.

When I run the generator, everything works well and the tensors seem to live on the GPU as expected,

```py
gen = generator_func()
(a, b), c = next(gen)

print(a.device)
print(b.device)
print(c.device)

"""
Output:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
```

But this fails when I try to use datasets:

```py
data_signature = (
    (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, None), dtype=tf.uint16),
     tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, None, 300), dtype=tf.float16)),
    tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1, None), dtype=tf.float32),
)

train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator_func, output_signature=data_signature)

for (a, b), c in train.take(1):
    print(a.device)
    print(b.device)
    print(c.device)

"""
Output:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

Sure, maybe the device scope changes when using Python generators. However, using the `copy_to_device` method does not fix the issue.

```py
train = train.apply(tf.data.experimental.copy_to_device("/gpu:0"))
```

I have also unsuccessfully tried using the `prefetch_to_device` method.

---

How would I go about debugging this? Why won't the tensors coming out of the Tensorflow Dataset go to the GPU memory?