# How is tensorflow.data.Dataset loading handled in the fit method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I wanted to know how data-loading and data transfer between CPU RAM and GPU memory is handled when I have a *tf.data.Dataset* and use the fit method of *Keras*.
Is one batch of data transferred at a time and then forward and backward propagation is done on that batch and then the new batch is sent from CPU RAM to GPU memory?
I know that in Keras's *fit* method there is *max_queue_size*, however, it says that

> "Used for generator or keras.utils.Sequence input only"

How does *tf.data* data-loading under the hood work? Does it change anything if instead of using the *fit* method I create a custom loop like [here](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/#using-the-gradienttape-a-first-endtoend-example)
Are there links/guides where this is explained in enough detail?

Comment: `model.fit` is very similar to custom loop you have linked. When you want the data, you call the `tf.data` iterator and it will generate data for you. How fast and how slow you get the data after the call, is based on your tf.data configuration. For example, If you set `prefetch`, the data will be fetched and kept in ram while the model is getting executed.

Comment: @V.M Internally, the fit method does not have a queue? (see max_queue_size of fit method of Keras)

Comment: `max_queue_size` is enabled for ` keras.utils.Sequence` generator and not for `tf.data`

Comment: So with a tf.data.Dataset when I use the fit method (or when I do a for loop on tf.data.Dataset) the data is passed one batch at a time from CPU RAM to GPU memory? Are you sure? Where can one find anything on this topic? @V.M

Comment: not true. Each batch just request data from `tf.data.generator`, whether the data is in ram or disk is how well you setup your `tf.data`.

Comment: https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/datapipeline/#best-practices, https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance

Comment: check `model.fit` https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1303-L1729

Comment: Mmmm, this is all unclear to me. What do you mean by "Each batch just request data from tf.data.generator"? 
I am using a tf.data.Dataset not a generator @V.M

Comment: For example, if you had a dataset like this:
`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(80000)
dataset = dataset.batch(64)`
How do I load it entirely into GPU memory and not one batch at a time?

Comment: See [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71330788/tensorflow-dataset-wont-output-tensors-to-gpu-memory)

Comment: `dataset` will run only on CPU, not on GPU.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you very much. Do you know if there is a method with Tensorflow to make the whole training set go to GPU? Do you know if it is possible for example with PyTorch? @V.M

Answer (score 0):

The dataset will be sampled sequentially, unless otherwise specified. Since you're in control of the dataset with `tf.data.Dataset`, you can perform this operation of it yourself, with [tf.data.Dataset.prefetch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch).

> Most dataset input pipelines should end with a call to prefetch. This allows later elements to be prepared while the current element is being processed. This often improves latency and throughput, at the cost of using additional memory to store prefetched elements.

```
>>> dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3)
>>> dataset = dataset.prefetch(2)
>>> list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: From what I know the prefetch method is only useful if I am doing preprocessing with the map operation in CPU.
It does not allow me to overlap the data transfer between CPU and GPU RAM ( it does not allow me while the GPU is doing forward and backward to load the next batch from CPU RAM to GPU memory).
This can be seen by measuring performance without the use of map

Comment: @pieters, your assumptions are wrong. nicolas is right about prefetch.