# What happens under the hood when I iterate a tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

When I create a tf.data.Dataset from, for example, a TFRecord file that is on disk, what happens under the hood when I iterate over the dataset itself?
And what happens when I iterate when I do the model training with keras/tensorflow? Like [here](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/#using-the-gradienttape-a-first-endtoend-example)

For example:

```
dataset_train = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(PATH_TFRECORD)
dataset_train = dataset_train.map(decode_function)
dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(64)
for (X_batch, y_batch) in dataset_train:
    model(X_batch, y_batch, training=True)
```

What happens here, if the training is done on GPU is that a for each batch, you read from disk until you get to RAM, decode the batch via "decode_function" and then send the batch from CPU RAM to GPU memory?
Or what happens is to read from disk all the TFRecord and load it into CPU RAM, decode all the elements via map, make the batches and then send the batches from CPU RAM to GPU memory?
What happens when there is a new epoch instead? Do I re-read the data from disk as TFRecord or do I already start from the data that is on RAM?
For each epoch do you copy the data then from CPU RAM to GPU memory even though the data is the same and the dataset fits there in memory?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this question different from the one yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74783732/how-is-tensorflow-data-dataset-loading-handled-in-the-fit-method We only allow one question per topic, no duplicates. This is not a forum.

Comment: This question is different, here the focus is on what happens by starting, for example, from a TfRecord dataset and iterating on it @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: To me it sounds the same, and also there are too many questions here, only one question per post.

Comment: Okay, but the question is not the same. However, you don't know the answer on the question? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Which question?, there are too many here.

Comment: In the code I showed above what happens is that I load the entire TFRecord from disk to CPU RAM? @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Stackoverflow being Stackoverflow. Always someone dedicating their time to making sure good questions get crapped on, while dumb, trivial questions get all the attention with 10 different, but equally meaningless answers. @pietrus I feel for you